# NPAPI plugin: nsScriptablePeer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _NPN_Evaluate referenced in function

Tags: npapi

I am trying to compile NPAPI plugin under Win-XP and VS 2008.
Its giving me error as `nsScriptablePeer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _NPN_Evaluate referenced in function` when I try to use `NPN_Evaluate` to call javascript function .  I have added all libraries from xulrunner-sdk/lib and xullrunner-sdk/sdk/lib in additional library directories. Is there any other library needs to be included to use `NPN_Evaluate` function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions beginning with `NPN_` are only accessible through the pointer passed during the initialization `NP_Initialize` phase.  I've been caught by this situation and I decided to document a bit [here](http://jldupont.blogspot.com/2009/11/notes-on-npapi-based-plugins.html).

In other words, you don't have to link a library **but** you have to catch the pointer to the NPN browser functions during the NP_Initialize call to your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a brief rundown of npapi plugins in general here:
http://colonelpanic.net/2009/03/building-a-firefox-plugin-part-one/

it's a little disjointed, but my goal was to answer some of the not-well-explained parts of NPAPI, like the one you ran into here =]

Incidently, if you're using nsScriptablePeer, you're using an outdated example that still uses XPCOM instead of NPObjects.  XPCOM will no longer be supported in future versions of firefox (starting 3.6, I believe)

A little more about that here: http://colonelpanic.net/2009/08/building-a-firefox-plugin-%E2%80%93-part-three/