# Accessing NPN_ methods from NPAPI plugin

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

I have a NPAPI plugin developed for Chrome. It works ok. But now I need to call NPN_GetValue from the plugin. The question is, how can I link (either statically, or dynamically) my code and what library/binary should be used for imports? I searched through all Chrome binaries and I did not find a single one, which contains NPN_ exports. Surely NPN_ methods must be provided by hosting browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NPAPI plugin: nsScriptablePeer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _NPN_Evaluate referenced in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742858/npapi-plugin-nsscriptablepeer-obj-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function pointers are provided to you as an argument to [NP_Initialize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NP_Initialize); it's your job to keep them around so that you can call them later. The functions aren't exported for you to link to.

Comment: Oops. I overlooked this. Thanks. I was misled by the fact that the header file contains prototypes for the functions themselves as well, not only typedefs for pointers in the NPNetscapeFuncs structure.